# Where can settlements be built near undiscovered hexes?

Tags: catan-explorers-pirates

The note in the rules for explorers and pirates states that "settlements may not be built on intersections adjacent to undiscovered hexes."  I am new to this expansion, does this mean that no undiscovered hex can be within two 'road lengths' of a settlement like the distance rule for settlements in base Catan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An intersection is formed at the point where three hexes meet. The intersection is hence adjacent to these three hexes. A settlement cannot be built if any of these three hexes is as yet undiscovered. The rule means nothing else, hence a settlement can definitely be built closer to an undiscovered hex than two road lengths away; it just has to be at least one road length away.

Answer (score -1):

" you can build a settlement in two ways: either along a road, just like in base Catan; OR, by landing a setler ship (...). You observe the distance rule in both cases" (p.5).
I assume the distance rule referred to is the base Catan distance rule of two road lengths away, at minimum.

Comment: This does not answer the question, which concerns placement relative to undiscovered hexes. Quoting a rule about a general point that does not address the specific point is not helpful.